# Apply Firebase to Android Studio Project version Bumblebee

Tags: android, firebase, gradle, build.gradle

I'm trying to add Firebase SDK, follow the step guide of Firebase:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CSKvB.png)

but the new version of Android Studio has a different build.gradle file, just:

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application' version '7.1.1' apply false
    id 'com.android.library' version '7.1.1' apply false
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

And I don't know how right to add code to my file. I've tried this:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        // Check that you have the following line (if not, add it):
        google()  // Google's Maven repository
    }
    dependencies {
        // Add this line
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.10'
    }
}

plugins {
    id 'com.android.application' version '7.1.1' apply false
    id 'com.android.library' version '7.1.1' apply false
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
allprojects {
    repositories {
        // Check that you have the following line (if not, add it):
        google()  // Google's Maven repository
    }
}
```

But the log here is:
*org.gradle.api.GradleScriptException: A problem occurred evaluating root project 'Uber clone'
Caused by: org.gradle.api.InvalidUserCodeException: Build was configured to prefer settings repositories over project repositories but repository 'Google' was added by build file 'build.gradle
at build_8l5l0a77l47futp20icywdlc2$_run_closure2$_closure3.doCall(D:\Android\AndroidProjects\Uberclone\build.gradle:25)
at build_8l5l0a77l47futp20icywdlc2$_run_closure2.doCall(D:\Android\AndroidProjects\Uberclone\build.gradle:23)
at build_8l5l0a77l47futp20icywdlc2.run(D:\Android\AndroidProjects\Uberclone\build.gradle:22)*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need to add the `repositories` and the `allprojects` inside the Gradle file. This is because both are already present inside the setting.gradle file. To solve this simply remove them as you can see below:

```
buildscript {
    dependencies {
        // Add this line
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.10'
    }
}

plugins {
    id 'com.android.application' version '7.1.1' apply false
    id 'com.android.library' version '7.1.1' apply false
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Comment: ohhh. thanks a lot. It's nice of u. I've fixed that

Answer (score -1):

I resolved this issue by commenting out 'dependencyResolutionManagement' section which is present in the settings.gradle.

Go to Gradle Scripts -> settings.gradle -> comment out 'dependencyResolutionManagement'

```
//dependencyResolutionManagement {
//    repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.FAIL_ON_PROJECT_REPOS)
//    repositories {
//        google()
//        mavenCentral()
//    }
//}
```

Then paste the all project repository in Gradle Scripts -> build.gradle -> paste it below 'plugins' section

like this-

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application' version '7.3.1' apply false
    id 'com.android.library' version '7.3.1' apply false
}


allprojects {
    repositories {
        // Make sure that you have the following two repositories
        google()  // Google's Maven repository
        mavenCentral()  // Maven Central repository
    }
}
```